# Table. How to save background color of col using colSpan?

Tags: html, html-table

Is it possible to save `col` background color using colpan? In example below I want to achive yellow color in space for last col even if I use `colspan="3"`.

Please, take a look to picture above, I want to achive this result using `colspan="3"`

[Solution example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGage.png)

[Wrong solution example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPHT0.png)

Thanks!

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2" style="background-color:#E6E6DC">
      <col style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Error descriotion, last col should be yellow</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5869207</td>
    <td>My first CSS</td>
    <td>$49</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

OP didn't make sense:

> - I want to achieve yellow color in space for last col even if I use colspan="3"
> - <del>Ok, I chopped up that large 3 rowspan and now the last column is yellow.</del>
> - Ok, kept middle row at `colspan='3'`, and used `<mark>` in order to hold the styles within the `<td>`. See updated Snippet.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table style='border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:325px;'>
    <colgroup>
      <col span="2" style="background-color:red">
        <col span='1' style="background-color:yellow">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
      <th>ISBN</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3' style='padding:0'>Error description, last col should 
        <mark style='line-height:1.2;width:12.25ex;border-right:1.75px solid yellow;border-left:3.75px solid yellow;display:inline-block;padding:0 12px 0 2px;position:relative; left: 3px;'>&nbsp;be yellow</mark>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5869207</td>
      <td>My first CSS</td>
      <td>$49</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, I get response with error. Errors contain different text. I can't use this solution. Thanks.

Comment: That makes very little sense. The table you made is valid. The table I made  that's based on your table is valid. Please review updated Snippet.

Comment: As I say early, I have a lot of different error-texts and very complex table. How do you imagine this solution in my case? You hardcoded the width, borders, etc... mark used for part of the text.. How I should calculate all of them? It's impossible, as for me. Thanks for your atention.

Comment: Now you make sense and have stated specifics. I have garnered more information from your last comment than your poorly worded question and the rest of your comments combined. Your tags are: [tag:html] and [tag:html-table], so I don't think you'll be able to calculate any dimensions without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add an "id" to your td colspan,

`<td colspan="3" id="your id here">Error descriotion, last col should be yellow</td>`

and add this to css

`#your id here{
 background-color: yellow;
}`

Comment: Last col should be yellow, not td... Thanks.

Comment: See last solution, that is what you need and actually there can just use
`table td[colspan="3"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to col and apply the same style for the colspan.

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table col.col-color, table td[colspan="3"]{
  background-color: yellow;
}

<table>
   <colgroup>
       <col span="2" style="background-color:red">
       <col class="col-color">
   </colgroup>
   <tr>
       <th>ISBN</th>
       <th>Title</th>
       <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Error descriotion, last col should be yellow</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>5869207</td>
        <td>My first CSS</td>
        <td>$49</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```